# Bootstrap Carousel Not Being Responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, carousel

I'm working on a simple landing page that has the bootstrap carousel at the top of the page. For the most part it works and resizes fine. If I go from a normal width to a small width browser it resizes fine. However when I make the browser size extra large everything on the page resizes except the carousel. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's a live link to the site: http://dev.mikefisherdesign.com/stackstrap

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The images inside your carousel appear to be around 960px wide so once the browser is resized beyond that the images are not stretching inside the carousel .item..

You should be able to fix this in your CSS with:

```
.item img {
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for 980 and small screens i did:

```
    @media (max-width: 979px) {
    #myCarousel.carousel img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    }
    }


    @media (max-width: 470px) {
    #myCarousel.carousel img {
    max-width:300%;
    width:150%;
    min-height: 300px;
    }
    }
```